# Dragged item not returning to correct position

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, angular-dragdrop, angulardraganddroplists

I'm using [angular drag and drop plugin](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop).
This issue occurs when i mouse scrolled my page to some distance. Then, dragged an item and released. The released item is returning to the wrong position (i.e.,) some pixels above than its actual position.
This issue occurs only in my angular app and cant be reproduced in any other places like jsfiddle or codepen. So, Screen Recorded the issue and uploaded in below link,
https://mega.nz/#!7s1FHTYL!VQf5OnU3iMOlZIQjn1oKiilVaRr6s2B_Py0l7mbl-Wo

Someone please help me on resolving this issue.. 
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the `ScrollTop` of the dragged element to 0, On the Event `OnDragStop(elem,event)`.. By doing so you can retain Original Position of the dragged element, on every drag method completes..